# Update Query issue in php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table 'tbl_size'

```
**Col Name**        **Data Type**   
size_id            int(11)  
pd_id              int(11)  
size_name          varchar(20)  
size_chart         int(6)   
qty                text
```

Now I'm trying to update this table with following query

```
$query="update tbl_size set `qty`='10' where `size_id`=335";
```

When i run this query in mysql, it works fine but when same thing i tries to do from php then it is updating `qty` to '0' and not to '10'.
I'm not getting why this is happening. Please help me to solve this problem.

New Updated Code :

```
// $rowvo['od_qty']=10;

// $row_1['qty']=20;

$sql = "SELECT qty  FROM tbl_size WHERE size_id =".$rowvo['size_id'];

$result = dbQuery($sql);

$row_1    = dbFetchAssoc($result);

$pqty=$row_1['qty']-$rowvo['od_qty'];

echo "Total Quantity Available Before Diduction : ".$row_1['qty'];

echo "Sold Quantity : ".$rowvo['od_qty'];

echo "Remaining Quantity : $pqty";

$sql_qty="update tbl_size set `qty`=$pqty where `size_id`=".$rowvo['size_id'];

echo "$sql_qty<br>";

$result_qty=mysql_query($sql_qty) or die('Error : '.mysql_error());

echo "No of Rows Affected : ".mysql_affected_rows()."<br>".mysql_error(); // 1
```

New Code with PDO :

```
try {
$b=$a->prepare("update tbl_size set `qty`=:qty where `size_id`=:size");
$b->bindValue(":size",$size_id);
$b->bindValue(":qty",$pqty);
$b->execute();

 } catch(PDOException $ex) {
echo "An Error occured!"; //user friendly message

}
```

and var_dump($ex)=NULL

Comment: Something is going wrong in your PHP code. Most likely due to code injection (I'm guessing). Can we see your **actual** PHP code where you make the call to the DB?

Comment: if qty is quantity, then why are you not using int ...?

Comment: If the problem is happening with your PHP, then why aren't you showing us your PHP?

Comment: You had better post your PHP code.

Comment: Might be due to a numeric value being cast to string because of single quotes ?

Comment: I have updated my code now I have changed data type of my 'qty' col to 'int' from 'text', still i getting same problem.

Comment: It's most likely because you're injecting variables. **This is why you should bind variables**. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: what is `echo "$sql_qty<br>";` showing? $pqty is really 10 in the query when you echo it?

Comment: @KURN : yes...and $sql_qty is update tbl_size set `qty`=10 where `size_id`=335

Comment: @h2ooooooo : even after using PDO i'm getting same problem.

Comment: @Pankaj **How** do you use PDO? It isn't enough just to paste a query. You'd want your query to be `UPDATE tbl_size SET qty = :qty WHERE size_id = :sizeID` and then bind `:qty` to `$qty`and `:sizeID` to `$rowvo['size_id']`.

Comment: Yeah i tried this too.

Comment: $a=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wwwbliss_db","root","");     
$b=$a->prepare("update tbl_size set `qty`=:qty where `size_id`=:size");
$b->bindParam(":size",$rowvo['size_id']);
$b->bindParam(":qty",$pqty);
$b->execute();

Comment: @Pankaj Don't you get an error in your try-catch then (`var_dump($ex)`)? Try `bindValue` instead.

Comment: @h2ooooooo : Please check updated PDO code and (var_dump($ex))...Still Its not working..

Answer (score 2):

Check the structure of your table you have text type for qty. It's possible that it is not of type char or varchar (or that it is and has a default value set to '0'). To resolve this you can use phpmyadmin, SQLyog or other MySql admin programs.

change your query

```
$sql_qty="update tbl_size set `qty`=$pqty where `size_id`=".$rowvo['size_id'];
```

to

```
$sql_qty="update tbl_size set `qty`='$pqty' where `size_id`='".$rowvo['size_id']."'";
```

Comment: I have updated my code now I have changed data type of my 'qty' col to 'int' from 'text', still i getting same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
Your Code       ==> `qty`= $pqty

Changes to this ==> `qty`='$pqty'
```

Comment: now i have changed data type of 'qty' to int that's why `qty`= $pqty

Comment: sitll it's not working ?  use below query $sql_qty="update tbl_size set `qty`= '$pqty' where `size_id`=".$rowvo['size_id'];

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$query="update tbl_size set qty=10 where size_id=335";
```

Comment: qty is text value field type so enter like this way  '10'